# Network (gigabit wired or wifi) utilisation very low ~5% on Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, router

I've got a HP Pavilion G6 which has decent specifications: Quad core, 8GB DDR3 ram, SSD, etc

I've got a problem with the networking. The inbound speed doesn't climb much above about 4% network utilisation, about 2.2Mb/s down (but strangely 8Mb/s up).

My fiber broadband which is 40Mb/s down and 10Mb/s up isn't the issue as my iPhone, iPad and other laptop don't have this issue. I can max out the internet connection easily with those devices and go much beyond that on the other laptop transferring large files via Gigabit lan.

I'm out of ideas as I don't understand how the laptop can have the same issue over wifi and wired, as it seems to be a limiting factor that's above the network layer, and can't be a driver issue as the wired and wireless lan adaptors are different and have different drivers.

Also, which I think is fairly critical info: I booted into a live linux distro on this same laptop with the issue and it wasn't an issue and I could max out the connections as you'd expect. So it's not a hardware issue.

Is there anything I can try? I'm open to all suggestions / further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it...

It was some software called "AMD Quick Stream" which is some kind of packet scheduling software I didn't ask for and wasn't aware had been parcelled in with the latest Catalyst control centre software.

I uninstalled it, and restarted the machine. Instantly I'm able to max out it's connections again.